# How do you access application variables in asp.net mvc 3 razor views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I set a Application variable in my global.asa.cs with:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...

        // load all application settings
        Application["LICENSE_NAME"] = "asdf";

    }
```

and then try to access with my razor view like this:

```
@Application["LICENSE_NAME"]
```

and get this error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Application' does not exist in the current context
```

what is the proper syntax?

Comment: Application variables? As in the .config file appSettings? (Please be more specific)

Comment: @Brad, He means Application state variables, if you look at the code it is pretty specific.

Comment: @Brad: I think he means values in the Application state object.

Comment: @Sanjeevakumar/@CodemOnkey: Dually noted. Thanks. ;-)

Comment: @BradChristie dually noted, ha!  I see what you did there.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Views are not supposed to pull data from somewhere. They are supposed to use data that was passed to them in form of a view model from the controller action. So if you need to use such data in a view the proper way to do it is to define a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string LicenseName { get; set; }
}
```

have your controller action populate it from wherever it needs to populate it (for better separation of concerns you might use a repository):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        LicenseName = HttpContext.Application["LICENSE_NAME"] as string
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally have your strongly typed view display this information to the user:

```
<div>@Model.LicenseName</div>
```

That's the correct MVC pattern and that's how it should be done.

Avoid views that pull data like pest, because today it's Application state, tomorrow it's a `foreach` loop, next week it's a LINQ query and in no time you end up writing SQL queries in your views.

Comment: +1 for pointing not only to a solution of the problem, but one that better follows the MVC pattern.

Comment: You can also create separate ActionResult that renders a partial view if you need to reuse some code, like in a header menu. I needed to send a model into a PartialView from my _Layout page, and wanted reusable code. I followed this pattern, and used **`@{Html.RenderAction("ActionName", "ControllerName");}`**. The Action returned a partial view.

Comment: Hi, I use same pattern but some code use static variables instead of application state. I'm really wondering what is right way?

Comment: How do you set data for the _layout view?

Comment: I think it should be `HttpContext.Current.Application["LICENSE_NAME"]` (added Current) shouldn't it?

Comment: This solution really helped me to understand the separation between view and controlle. Thanks kind sir, and +1. As a side note, there are more answers here at SO using linq queries in View than not.... maybe there's something we can do?

Answer (score 25):

```
@HttpContext.Current.Application["someindex"]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get the current Application using the automatically generated [`ApplicationInstance` property](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/02/dissecting-razor-part-5-use-source-luke.html):

```
@ApplicationInstance.Application["LICENSE_NAME"]
```

However, this logic does not belong in the view.

Comment: This works, but Visual Studio and or Resharper does not like it. The IDE likes the @HttpContext.Current.Application["someindex"] better, even if they are not best practices.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to access this via `HttpContext.Current.Application[]`, however MVC best practices would state that you should probably consider passing this through your View Model.

Answer (score 4):

Building on @Darin-Dimitrov pattern answered above, I passed a model into a partial view, which I loaded into a _Layout page.

I needed to load a web page from an external resource on Application Load, which will be used as the header navigation across multiple sites. This is in my Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    Application["HeaderNav"] = GetHtmlPage("https://site.com/HeaderNav.html");
}

static string GetHtmlPage(string strURL)
{
    string strResult;
    var objRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL);
    var objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        strResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
    }
    return strResult;
}
```

Here is my controller Action for the partial view.

```
public class ProfileController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult HeaderNav()
    {
        var model = new Models.HeaderModel
        {
            NavigationHtml = HttpContext.Application["HeaderNav"] as string
        };
        return PartialView("_Header", model);
    }
}
```

I loaded the partial view in the _Layout page like this.

```
<div id="header">
     @{Html.RenderAction("HeaderNav", "Profile");}
</div>
```

The partial view _Header.cshtml is very simple and just loads the html from the application variable.

```
@model Models.HeaderModel
@MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.NavigationHtml)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        var e = "Hello";
        Application["value"] = e;
    }
```

@HttpContext.Current.Application["value"]

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in an MVC controller and had to make fully qualified HttpContext for it to work ..

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["VarName"]
```