# How to share a variable between views asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I need to access UserId from all my asp.net mvc application in order to use it for hiding/show some elements:

the UserId the Primary Key in user tables (in SQL server).

in normal asp.net I have used a BasePage:Page and added:

```
public long FinKaynUserId
{
   //long FinKaynUserId = 0;
   get
   {
       if (HttpContext.Current.Session["FinKaynUserId"] != null && Convert.ToInt64(HttpContext.Current.Session["FinKaynUserId"]) != 0)
           return Convert.ToInt64(HttpContext.Current.Session["FinKaynUserId"]);
       else
       {
           HttpCookie myCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["FinKaynUserId"];
           if (myCookie != null)
           {
               HttpContext.Current.Session["FinKaynUserId"] = Convert.ToInt64(myCookie.Value);
               // Session["User"] = (new UserManager()).GetUser(Convert.ToInt64(Session["UserId"]));
               return  Convert.ToInt64(HttpContext.Current.Session["FinKaynUserId"]);
           }
           else
              return 0;
       }
   }
   set
   {
       HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("FinKaynUserId");
       cookie.Value = value.ToString();
       cookie.Secure = false;
       cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
       HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Add(cookie);
       HttpContext.Current.Session["FinKaynUserId"] = value;
   }

}
```

How can i do the same thing in asp.net mvc.

Comment: i want to share a UserId between views .if the session is expired ,check cookies.

Comment: Here's another SO relevant post with MVC specific guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286301/how-do-you-access-application-variables-in-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-views

Comment: You can still use the Session variables in asp.net MVC applications, but i suggest use built-in asp.net FormsAuthentication instead of managing sessions and cookies by yourself

Comment: Thanks sos.FormsAuthentication store username in a cookie.UserName is not unique in my users table (in sql server).i have to work with UserId or Email.users are authenticated with (Email,Pass)==>Get UserId==>use in all views.Is that possible with FormsAuthentication?

Comment: You don't have to use the real username as the FormsAuthentication tickets, you can tell FormsAuthentication to store anything you like such as user's `emailaddress` or `userid` and then retrieve stored ticket (key) using `User.Identity.Name`

Comment: sos,i have done that:FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserId.ToString(), false) the problem that i have a menu where i should display "UserName","Sign in Or Sign ou" depending on "isAuthenticated" .How can i get the UserName after login(in the master page)?

Comment: +knowing that UserId is what is stored in the cookie(not UserName)?

Comment: from your database of course, you can make a query to db each time or have a dictionary of online users for sake of efficiency (with userId as the key and Username or other user info as the value)

Answer (score 1):

HttpContext.Current.Session["Session_User"] = value;

Answer (score 1):

If the variable usage is at session level then use: `Session["Variable"]="value";`
Or else if usage is across the application, then use: `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["Variable"]="value";`

Answer (score -2):

One option is to store your variable in the application context:

```
Application["FinKaynUserId"] = value;
```

And then you can just get it in other code section like this:

```
if (Application["FinKaynUserId"] != null)
{
    long FinKaynUserId = (long)Application["FinKaynUserId"];
}
```

Comment: Application variables are global variables which are shared throughout all requests, so it's not a good place to store user id. Use Session variables instead

Comment: It's a session variable.not an application variable.

Comment: @user594166 my comment was on Stas answer and usage of Application["FinKaynUserId"]