# MVC access application variable in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you access application variables in asp.net mvc 3 razor views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286301/how-do-you-access-application-variables-in-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-views)

Is it possible to access application variable in controller using asp.net mvc2.0

Comment: can you be more specific

Comment: i have declared application variable in global.asax file now want to assign value in controller

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For example, in global.asax:

```
Application["AppVar"] = "hello";
```

In any controller method:

```
string appVar = HttpContext.Application["AppVar"] as string;
```

**Update (7/2018):**
If you need to access MVC global application data from a DLL library:

```
using System.Web;
....
if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Application != null)
    string appVar = HttpContext.Current.Application["AppVar"] as string;
```

It is safer to check HttpContext.Current.Application against null as well, because some fake httpcontext library (used in unit test projects) could have a valid context with null "Application".